# Android developer converting to iOS: How to reference UILabel and change the text

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I've developed a few `Android` applications, but recently I've been looking to develop some `iOS` apps. After reading a few [tutorials](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-basic-how-does-the-hello-world-app-work/) I tried to make a really basic app to see if I'd understood.

I have a `UILabel` and two `UIButtons`. One `UIButton` increments an `NSInteger` variable, and the other `UIButton` decreases the same integer. My idea is that I display this integer in using the `UILabel`.

For an `Android` app to access an equivalent type of structure, and change the text, I would use the following code:

```
TextView my_label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_label);
my_label.setText(""+integer_i_want_to_display);
```

Essentially I'd like to know the `iOS` equivalent of the above `Android` code. I'm using `SDK 7.0` and `Xcode 5.0.2`.

Comment: Look for `stringWithFormat`

Comment: No homework, no assistance...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UIViewController you can define an IBOutlet in your .h file and connect it to a UILabel in the .xib file. e.g. so:
.h file:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
    NSInteger integer_i_want_to_display;
}
```

.m file:

```
- (void)someAction {
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", integer_i_want_to_display];
}
```